# Показать баннер если заблокирована реклама

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, но не показывает баннер. Если пользователь зашел на сайт с блокировщиком показать сообщение(баннер). Сам код рекламы оборачиваем в div и если он блокируется показать баннер сообщение об отключении.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function() {
    if (jQuery('#adsbygoogle').height() == 0) { 
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Сообщене пользователю отключить рекламу'; 
    } 
}, 3000);
</script>


<div id="adsbygoogle">Рекламный баннер тутуутутуту от гугла код</div>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуйте с блокировщиком и нет:

```js
var adBlockEnabled = false;
var testAd = document.createElement('div');
var download = document.getElementsByClassName('reklama');
testAd.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
testAd.className = 'adsbox';
document.body.appendChild(testAd);
window.setTimeout(function() {
  if (testAd.offsetHeight === 0) {
    adBlockEnabled = true;
    document.querySelector('.info').classList.add("info__active");
    document.querySelector('.info').classList.add("info__active");
  }
  testAd.remove();
  console.log('AdBlock Enabled? ', adBlockEnabled)
}, 1200);
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}

.info__active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="reklama">Реклама</div>
<div class="info">Сообщение</div>
```

Comment: Это просто нет слов, это гениально просто, нет Я не шучу это суппер, нет это нет слов как это мастерство назвать. Все тесты всех блокировщиков на ура просто прошел )))

Comment: Ну конечно ))) Я же написал что все тесты Ваш скрипт прошел на ура. Все блокировщики 5 штук разновидностей. Всех заметил и вывел баннер ))) Спасибо огромное Вам )))

Comment: Спасибо огромное и Вам ))) Пишите если что может чем смогу Вам помочь )))